# Delete from a list everything except of values from a different list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of 'Trips' that contains a list of all tickets for that particular trip. I also do have entity Customers that holds a list of Tickets only for that customer.

What I would like to achieve is from having a customer with all his tickets create a list of Trips that would only contain tickets for that customer. That would later on allow me to loop for that user through trips that this user has tickets to and then for tickets of that user.

```
public class Trip
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SeatNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

My idea is to from the list of customer tickets retrieve all trips and create a list of unique trips and then loop through tickets and then delete all tickets except the ones customer owns (I couldn't really get the removing part), my not finished solution:

```
Customer customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId.Equals(user.Id));
List<Trip> Trips = customer.Tickets.Select(u => u.Trip).Distinct().ToList();
Trips = Trips.ForEach(t=>t.Tickets.RemoveAll(u=>u.))
```

Update:

Trips table contains all trips with all tickets.

Customer table contains all tickets for that customer.

I want to create a List of Trips that will only contain tickets for specified user.

When I retrieve the list of trips right now it will contain all the tickets.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Kevin how to get rid of all the tickets for List Trips that are not customer's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework (*and I assume you are based on the tags and the question*) you should disable lazy loading. This will force you to specify what related entities you want to retrieve when querying the database which is good because you do not get unexpected hits due to data sizes.

Once you do that you can retrieve just the data of interest like so

```
var customer = db.Customers
    .Include(cust => cust.Tickets.Select(ticket => ticket.Trip))
    .SingleOrDefault(cust => cust.UserId == user.Id);
```

The `Include` and inner `Selecet` will ensure that you retrieve the tickets and the associated trip on each ticket but only as it relates to that user.

This is a good thing as if you are using lazy loading what happens if there is a user that likes to cruise a lot so they have many tickets on trips which also have many tickets. Then for each trip you will be retrieving a massive amount of data from the db. You wont realize there is a problem until your database has grown in data volume though.

To disable lazy loading add this in the body of the constructor of your `DbContext` type.

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

---

### Edit

> ... could you give me something that would work with what I have right now

```
Trips.ForEach(trip => trip.Tickets.RemoveAll(ticket => ticket.Customer.Id != user.Id));
```

Although this could save you another set of trips to the database, add `CustomerId` to your `Ticket` entity.

```
Trips.ForEach(trip => trip.Tickets.RemoveAll(ticket => ticket.CustomerId != user.Id));
```

- `ForEach` does not return anything, it just iterates over the `List<T>`
- `RemoveAll` returns an int and modifies the actual collect (*ie. does not return a new List*)

Comment: A lot of my code depends on lazy loading and this isn't enterprise grade program anyway. I really do appreciate your answer but could you give me something that would work with what I have right now?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly that you want a list of all trips the customer has a ticket to, you can do something like this:

```
Customer.Trips = Trips.Where((trip) => trip.Tickets.Any((ticket) => customer.Tickets.Contains(ticket)));
```